# cpp - how to get login failed event programmatically in windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I am trying to get the login successful and failure event programmatically.
By using SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE event, I am getting login successful event.
Now I am trying to get login failed event.

Is anyone know how we can get login failure event by using cpp?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can, since GINA is a secure system. Maybe take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?

Comment: There is no service event when a login fail. You may have to resort to monitoring the System Event Log for error messages related to failed logins. See [Consuming Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910.aspx) and [Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx).